# How to filter ISO 8601 dates with a particular year

Tags: date, liquid

In Adobe Business Catalyst, it stores dates in ISO 8601 format E.G. 1989-08-01T00:00:00

They provide a means of retrieving these dates like so:

```
{module_data resource="customers" version="v3" fields="firstName,middleName,anniversary" skip="0" limit="10" where="\{'id':'{{memberId}}'\}" order="id" collection="crmData"}
```

Which outputs the following for anniversay:

```
[anniversary1, 1987-08-01T00:00:00][anniversary1Title, Start Year][anniversary2, 1989-08-01T00:00:00][anniversary2Title, End Year][anniversary3, ][anniversary3Title, ][anniversary4, ][anniversary4Title, ][anniversary5, ][anniversary5Title, ]
```

I would like to retrieve only the records with a certain year (E.G. 1989). I've tried the following, but I'm pretty sure 'contains' is the wrong way to be going about this:

```
{module_data resource="customers" version="v3" fields="id,firstName,lastName" skip="0" limit="10" where="\{'anniversary.anniversary2':\{'$contains':'1989'\}\}" order="id" collection="crmData"}
```

I can find the record I'm looking for when I hard code the date (including month and year):

```
{module_data resource="customers" version="v3" fields="id,firstName,lastName" skip="0" limit="10" where="\{'anniversary.anniversary2':'1989-08-01'\}" order="id" collection="crmData"}
```

Just need a little help to make this work when I only know the year. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick.

```
{% assign first = "2016-01-01T00:00:00" -%}
{{first}}
{% assign last = "2017-01-01T00:00:00" -%}
{{last}}
{module_data resource="customers" version="v3" fields="id,firstName,lastName" skip="0" limit="10" where="\{'$and':\[\{'anniversary.anniversary1':\{'$lt':'{{last}}'\}\},\{'anniversary.anniversary1':\{'$gt':'{{first}}'\}\}\]\}" order="id" collection="myData"}

<div>
<pre>{{myData|json}}</pre>
</div>
```

Let me know if you need more help.